# I am unable to solve this :java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 54

Tags: java, io

I want to add(sum) the integer values stored  in two text files and show the summation as output but after running the code it gives an exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String path="C:/Users/MYPC/Desktop/text.txt";
    String path2="C:/Users/MYPC/Desktop/temp.txt";    
    FileReader fr=null;
    FileReader fr2=null;
    try{
        fr=new FileReader(path); 
        fr2=new FileReader(path2);
        int i,sum=0;
        int i2; 
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(path);
        sc=new Scanner(path2);
        while((i=fr.read())!=-1 &&((i2=fr2.read())!=-1 )) {
             int read1=sc.nextInt(i);
             int read2=sc.nextInt(i2);
             sum = sum + read1+read2;     
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        System.out.println(sum);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally{
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you ask a question involving an Exception you should always include the full stack trace produced by the exception.

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 54 ,This is what it gives me exception

Comment: Rather than catching the exception and just printing its message, let it get thrown so that your environment (IDE or command line) will show the entire stack trace. Then add it to your question. That will show us which line the error occurs on, and what the sequence of calls is before the error happens. Also show the contents of the files -- at least the first few lines.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I will improve my code

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 54
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
 at java.util.Scanner.buildIntegerPatternString(Scanner.java:423)
 at java.util.Scanner.integerPattern(Scanner.java:443)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at fileaverage.FileAverage.main(FileAverage.java:35)

Comment: What do you think that error means? You still need to add the exception stack trace and the file contents to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing a number to the `nextInt` method, you are specifying the radix. So if for example at a given iteration you have `2` for the value of `i`, you're telling it you need binary. If you leave the radix out it will scan in base 10.

That said, `read()` of `FileReader` reads the next character so you don't need a scanner to scan for the next integer anywhere.

Change the code inside your try block as follows (not tested):

```
fr = new FileReader(path);
fr2 = new FileReader(path2);
while ((i = fr.read()) != -1 && (i2 = fr2.read()) != -1) {
    char c = (char) i;
    char c2 = (char) i2;
    if (Character.isDigit(c) && Character.isDigit(c2)) {
        int n = Character. getNumericValue(c);
        int n2 = Character.getNumericValue(c2);
        sum += (n + n2);
    } else {
        // TODO handle this somehow
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx a lot sir ,You saved my day

Comment: The is perfectly running  after i added your code :)

Answer (score -1):

why you write below:
fr2=new FileReader("");

and then use fr2 to read
  (i2=fr2.read())!=-1 )

So, where fr2 to read, its path is empty string.

Comment: now it gives me exception that :-java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 54